# makings a bins column with dates in python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, time, bins

In python i have data that looks like this with 500.000 rows :

TIME                             count

1-1-1900  10:41:00            1

3-1-1900 09:54:00         1

4-1-1900  15:45:00            1

5-1-1900  18:41:00            1

4-1-1900  15:45:00            1

and i want to make a new column with bins in quarters like this:

bins                            count

9:00-9:15         2

9:15-9:30             4

9:30-9:45             4

10:00-10:15           4

i know how you make bins, but the timestamp gives me troubles.
Can somebody help me with this?
already thank you!

Comment: does the date matter?

Comment: you mean the 1-1-1900? no that can be away. i tried to get that away, but then it says it have to be a string and not a time or datestamp. So i don't know how to let this work

Comment: What do you mean by "but the timestamp gives me trouble"? And do you specifically need to use `datetime` objects?

Comment: i wanted to make the column TIME shorter with this:

Comment: x=data["TIME"].map(lambda x: x[:2])
datetime.strptime(data["TIME"], '%H%M')

Comment: but was not working, because it is a datetime. i dont have to wokr with datetime objects, but i get the data like this, so it is already datetime object.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late. But better late than never. I also came across a similar requirement and done by using [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) library.

- First, Load data in pandas data-frame
- Second, check TIME column must be datetime object and not object type (like string or whatever). You can check it by

  `df.info()`

for example, in my case TIME column was initially of object type i.e. string type

```html
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 17640 entries, 0 to 17639
Data columns (total 3 columns):
TIME           17640 non-null object
value          17640 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 413.5+ KB
```

- if that is the case, then convert it to pandas datetime object by using this command

  `df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])`
  ignore this if already in datetime format

`df.info()` now gives updated format

```html
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 RangeIndex: 17640 entries, 0 to 17639
 Data columns (total 3 columns):
 TIME           17640 non-null datetime64[ns]
 value          17640 non-null int64
 dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(1)
 memory usage: 413.5 KB
```

- Now our dataframe is ready for magic :)

  ```python
     counts = pd.Series(index=df.TIME, data=np.array(df.count)).resample('15T').count()
     print(counts[:3])
  ```

  ```html
   TIME
   2017-07-01 00:00:00    3
   2017-07-01 00:15:00    3
   2017-07-01 00:30:00    3
   Freq: 15T, dtype: int64
  ```

  in above command `15T` means 15minutes bucket, you can replace it with `D` for day bucket, `2D` for 2 days bucket, `M` for month bucket, `2M` for 2 months bucket and so on. You can read the detail of these notations on this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas.Series.resample)
- now, our buckets data is done as you can see above. for time range use this command. Use the same time range as of data. In my case, my data was 3 months so I am creating time-range of 3 months.

```python
 r = pd.date_range('2017-07', '2017-09', freq='15T')
 x = np.repeat(np.array(r), 2, axis=0)[1:-1]
 # now reshape data to fit in Dataframe
 x = np.array(x)[:].reshape(-1, 2)
 # now fit in dataframe and print it
 final_df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['start', 'end'])
 print(final_df[:3])
```

```html
                  start                 end
0   2017-07-01 00:00:00 2017-07-01 00:15:00
1   2017-07-01 00:15:00 2017-07-01 00:30:00
2   2017-07-01 00:30:00 2017-07-01 00:45:00
```

date ranges also done

- Now append count and dateranges to get final outcome

  ```python
   final_df['count'] = np.array(means)
   print(final_df[:3])
  ```

```html
                  start                 end count
0   2017-07-01 00:00:00 2017-07-01 00:15:00     3
1   2017-07-01 00:15:00 2017-07-01 00:30:00     3
2   2017-07-01 00:30:00 2017-07-01 00:45:00     3
```

Hope anyone find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure that this is what you asked for. If it's not, I would recommend you to improve your question, because it's very hard to understand your problem. In particular, it would be nice to see what you've already tried to do.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import product
from datetime import time
from StringIO import StringIO


MAX_HOURS = 23
MAX_MINUTES = 59


def process_data_file(data_file):
    """
    The data_file is supposed to be an opened file object
    """
    time_entry = namedtuple("time_entry", ["time", "count"])
    data_to_bin = []
    for line in data_file:
        t, count = line.rstrip().split("\t")
        t = map(int, t.split()[-1].split(":")[:2])
        data_to_bin.append(time_entry(time(*t), int(count)))
    return data_to_bin


def make_milestones(min_hour=0, max_hour=MAX_HOURS, interval=15):
    minutes = [minutes for minutes in xrange(MAX_MINUTES+1) if not minutes % interval]
    hours = range(min_hour, max_hour+1)
    return [time(*milestone) for milestone in list(product(hours, minutes))]


def bin_time(data_to_bin, milestones):
    time_entry = namedtuple("time_entry", ["time", "count"])
    data_to_bin = sorted(data_to_bin, key=lambda time_entry: time_entry.time, reverse=True)
    binned_data = []
    current_count = 0
    upper = milestones.pop()
    lower = milestones.pop()
    for entry in data_to_bin:
        while not lower <= entry.time <= upper:
            if current_count:
                binned_data.append(time_entry("{}-{}".format(str(lower)[:-3], str(upper)[:-3]), current_count))
                current_count = 0
            upper, lower = lower, milestones.pop()
        current_count += entry.count
    return binned_data


data_file = StringIO("""1-1-1900 10:41:00\t1
3-1-1900 09:54:00\t1
4-1-1900 15:45:00\t1
5-1-1900 18:41:00\t1
4-1-1900 15:45:00\t1""")


binned_time = bin_time(process_data_file(data_file), make_milestones())
for entry in binned_time:
    print(entry.time, entry.count, sep="\t")
```

The output:

```
18:30-18:45 1
15:45-16:00 2
10:30-10:45 1
```

Comment: i wanted to. But i need a reputation of 15 points. a friend of mine vote up one now.

Comment: @camiel1985 you don't need reputation of 15 to accept an answer. There is the check-box under the rate arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying without pandas:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime as dt
from itertools import groupby

def bin_ts(dtime, delta):
    modulo = dtime.timestamp() % delta.total_seconds()
    return dtime - dt.timedelta(seconds=modulo)

src_data = [
    ('1-1-1900 10:41:00', 1),
    ('3-1-1900 09:54:00', 1),
    ('4-1-1900 15:45:00', 1),
    ('5-1-1900 18:41:00', 1),
    ('4-1-1900 15:45:00', 1)
]

ts_data = [(dt.datetime.strptime(ts, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), count) for ts, count in src_data]

bin_size = dt.timedelta(minutes=15)

binned = [(bin_ts(ts, bin_size), count) for ts, count in ts_data]

def time_fmt(ts):
    res = "%s - %s" % (ts.strftime('%H:%M'), (ts + bin_size).strftime('%H:%M'))
    return res

binned_time = [(time_fmt(ts), count) for ts, count in binned]

cnts = defaultdict(int)
for ts, group in groupby(binned_time, lambda x: x[0]):
    for row in group:
        cnts[ts] += row[1]

output = list(cnts.items())

output.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(output)
```

result in:

```
[('09:45 - 10:00', 1),
 ('10:30 - 10:45', 1),
 ('15:45 - 16:00', 2),
 ('18:30 - 18:45', 1)]
```