# How to discretize a datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, discretization

I have a dataset that contains a column of datetime of a month, and I need to divide it into two blocks (day and night or am\pm) and then discretize the time in each block into 10mins bins. I could add another column of 0 and 1 to show it is am or pm, but I cannot discretize it! Can you please help me with it?

```
df['started_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['started_at'])
df['start hour'] = df['started_at'].dt.hour.astype('int')
df['mor/aft'] = np.where(df['start hour'] < 12, 1, 0)
df['started_at']

0          16:05:36
2          06:22:40
3          16:08:10
4          12:28:57
6          15:47:30
             ...   
3084526    15:24:24
3084527    16:33:07
3084532    14:08:12
3084535    09:43:46
3084536    17:02:26
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makings a bins column with dates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151552/makings-a-bins-column-with-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are trying to add a column for every interval of ten minutes to indicate if an observation is from that interval of time.

You can use `lambda expressions` to loop through each observation from the series.

Dividing by 10 and making this an integer gives the first digit of the minutes, based on which you can add indicator columns.

I also included how to extract the day indicator column with a `lambda expression` for you to compare. It achieves the same as your `np.where()`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'started_at': ['14:20:56', 
                   '00:13:24', 
                   '16:01:33']
})

# convert column to datetime
df['started_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['started_at'])

# make day indicator column
df['day'] = df['started_at'].apply(lambda ts: 1 if ts.hour > 12 else 0)

# make indicator column for every ten minutes
for i in range(24):
    for j in range(6):
        col = 'hour_' + str(i) + '_min_' + str(j) + '0'
        df[col] = df['started_at'].apply(lambda ts: 1 if int(ts.minute/10) == j and ts.hour == i else 0)

print(df)
```

Output first columns:

```
           started_at  day  hour_0_min_00  hour_0_min_10  hour_0_min_20  
0 2021-11-21 14:20:56    1              0              0              0   
1 2021-11-21 00:13:24    0              0              1              0   
2 2021-11-21 16:01:33    1              0              0              0   
...
...
...
```

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you.